# Suggested Web Stress Test Scenarios

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, load-testing, stress-testing

does anyone know of any web application stress testing "best practice" documents? I'm about to load test a .NET 4 site using VS2010's tester and would like to have an outline to work from to ensure i'm covering all my bases (or as many as possible).

So for instance, id hope that the document would be the type that says, "try pushing x users over y time" and "x concurrent users over y time." But then again i have no idea. Thats why i need your help.

Thanks all, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen the article on .NET application performance testing from MSDN?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647788.aspx